# lots of /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL process but there's no file in that path

Tags: process, httpd

I'm having issue with 100% CPU usage caused by suspicious processes.

One of them is
`/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL`, and running as `www-data` user process.
But what's interesting is there's no apache folder under `/usr/local`.

My server has nginx running as the web server, and there's no apache installed.
I have to regularly kill these processes as it's making my nginx not respond.

Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks

Comment: I believe [a program can change its `argv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24407295). What is the output of `readlink /proc/<PID of the suspicious process>/exe`?

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't output anything..

Comment: I also see `www-data 28475 29.3  0.2  24380  5408 ?        R    09:16  93:08 [sync_supers]` often.. which is also very suspicious.

Comment: `readlink` doesn't output anything? You may have no access. What about `sudo readlink /proc/<PID of the suspicious process>/exe`? Further digging in `/proc/<PID of the suspicious process>/` may help. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1326752/432690).

Comment: sudo actually worked! It's `/usr/bin/perl`