# Find file running on python port hosting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have a `localhost:5000` port that is hosted by `python3` server in `ubuntu`. How to i know which file it serves without knowing anything extra?

I am using `lsof -i :5000` and i only know that it is hosted by python 3.
I am trying to locate the file/folder hosted by that that without any extra knowledge given. The thing i know that yes, there is some file being hosted at port 5000 using python3. But i dunno what is the name of the file hosted and which directory it is located.

Also tried `fuser 5000/tcp -v` but id dones not show the file hosted.

Is that possible and what command do i need to get all file/folder hosted by it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsof` should have told you the PID of the process. Let's call it `$pid`. Investigate what is inside `/proc/$pid/`. Some of the following commands may require root access (i.e. you may want to `sudo su -` beforehand).

```
cd /proc/$pid
readlink exe      # the executable
readlink cwd      # current working directory
xxd cmdline       # command line (xxd useful because items are null-separated)

cd /proc/$pid/fd
ls -l             # file descriptors in use
```

Additionally interact with the server (e.g. download the file) while using `strace` to see what it does. See this answer: [*how to investigate what a process is doing?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769164)

Or you can download the file and try to find a duplicate by comparing the content. Preliminary comparison by size may speed things up greatly.

```
file="/path/to/the/downloaded/file"
size=`<"$file" wc -c`

# now you will probably want to use sudo
find / -type f ! -path "/proc/*" ! -path "/sys/*" ! -path "/dev/*" -size ${size}c -exec cmp -s "$file" {} \; -print

unset -v file size    # just to clean
```

Note I excluded `/proc/`, `/sys/` and `/dev/`. You may also get familiar with `-xdev` (see [`man 1 find`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/find/)) and use it maybe.