# Retrieve process information from nohup command

Tags: linux, operating-systems, nohup

I use `nohup` command to run shell scripts as the following:

```
nohup ./run.sh &
```

My question is: After logging out the terminal and coming back later, how can I retrieve the information about this process if it is finished or still running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can examine the output of `ps x`. Either there is `run.sh` there or not. If there is, it may be the process you seek or some other `run.sh`. Further investigation may be required.

There is however this trick. Note `nohup` prints a message like this:

> ```
>  nohup: ignoring input and appending output to /home/alli/nohup.out
> ```

Now invoke:

```
lsof /home/alli/nohup.out
```

If your `run.sh` invoked with `nohup` is still running, it should appear in the output of `lsof` (twice, because `nohup` redirects file descriptor `1` and `2` to `nohup.out`). If you used `nohup` more than once, `lsof` should return multiple processes. If you used `nohup` more than once with the same executable, you may need to check `/proc/$pid/` ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1326752/432690)) to tell them apart.

I would use [`tmux`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) in the first place. In fact I do use it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value of the `nohup`ped process in a file using `$!` right after you started the process with

```
nohup the_process &
```

Then when you come back read the PID and check if the process is running. If yes, check if it's the kind of process you want. (The PID might have been reassigned to another process.)

If it doesn't disrupt the process's functioning, you can also pass the process a fake argument that will act as a hint for you when you read the output of `ps`. Eg.:

```
$ cat p.bash 
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
$ nohup ./p.bash some_id_hint &
[1] 14139
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
$ echo $!
14139
$ ps 14139
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
14139 pts/1    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./p.bash some_id_hint
```